# Why HA cluster have been deprecated in Neo4j 4.0?

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing

HA cluster have been deprecated in Neo4j 4.0,why do this change?

Answer (score 0):

Answering as a Neo4j employee.

Perhaps this is a better fit for asking on the [Neo4j community forums](https://community.neo4j.com/), but HA clustering has been deprecated for some time, and no new features or development has been happening there for awhile, so with the 4.0 major release we are following through on the already-established deprecation and removing it.

[Causal clustering](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/) has been the recommended Neo4j clustering approach for several years now, and is more robust than HA (for example, avoiding split-brain issues that can occur in HA, which results in branched data).

Comment: And just to note...both HA clustering and causal clustering are highly available. You aren't losing out on high availability by using causal clustering.

Comment: I see HA clustering has been deprecated, but I don't know why the enginer of Neo4j  do that, maybe there are any shortcomings?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned HA has shortcomings (the split-brain issue that I mentioned that can result in branched data). That isn't present in causal clustering.